# Iframe Content Not Rendering Under Scroll In iOs5 iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iframe, scroll

I'm developing iPad html5 webpage that needs to display pages from other origins (different domains).

I'm loading those pages into `iframe`, and scrolling the `iframe` using the iOs5 new scrolling ability, as shown in the code below.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="height: 1185px; width: 100%; overflow:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/11946/scrolling-iframe-on-ipad/p1"></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is that the off-screen iframe content is not becoming visible when scrolling to it (the frame is blank).

How can I overcome this issue and provide scrollable `iframe` solution?

Comment: Solved, I'll post answer later..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK. found the solution.
apparently, the problem appear when the main document height is shorter than the `iframe` that is scrolled.
the parts of the iframe page, that exceed the document height, are not rendered.

So, under my needs, I could solve the problem by adding such a js (with jquery) code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
     var iframe = $("#myIframe");    
     iframe.load(function() {
         $("body").height(iframe.height());
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone know how todo this with ExtJS or native JS as I don't have jQuery available there?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an access to iFrame body, apply some transform3d to its content to enable GPU rendering.

In my case adding `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);` to main wrapping div did the job.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case, I had to set this style on my frame which had `height: 100%` set in the CSS.

Comment: For me this didn't work and I created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55068656/safari-mobil-iframe-content-out-of-view-not-rendered