# iFrame on iPad isn't rendering entire content inside

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, iframe

I managed to get iFrame/HTML-object scrolling on the iPad (iOS 5.1) to work. But there are still some problems.

One such problem is, that when I scroll the iFrame around the iPad screen it seems that the render engine of Safari isn't able to reload the content of the area - and that it just becomes visible before scrolling. Hope everyone understands what I mean. You can try it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4118251/scrollSample.html) It's a very basic page just to demonstrate the problem. Has anyone here encountered this problem and has a solution?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8923541

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iframe Content Not Rendering Under Scroll In iOs5 iPad/iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912218/iframe-content-not-rendering-under-scroll-in-ios5-ipad-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You can using the following javascript that would act just like an iframe, but renders better:

```
$("#divID").load("index.html");
```