# Fancybox iframe not showing everything on iOS

Tags: ios5, fancybox

I am using iframe in Fancybox 1.3.4 to show web page samples. Some pages contain large amount of images and can be very long.

It works perfectly on all other devices except iOS.

The pop-up window loads the content at first, but it stops loading in a short time. So basically, people can only see top part of the web page on their iOS devices. When they scroll down in pop-up window, all they see is blank. Sometimes, if they are lucky and have a fast internet, they might be able to see more...

I am not sure if this is the issue with iOS or Fancybox.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Milo

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/q/8912218/1055987?

Comment: @JFK I checked the solution in your link. Now 99% the iframe content can be rendered. I say 99% because there is always a few pixels(maybe 40?) missing at the bottom of the iframe. Any idea why?

Comment: Not idea but maybe you can try making the parent page 10% longer