# Fancybox and overlay on iphone and ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ipad, fancybox

I'm working with fancybox now and it works fine but not with ajax content which is bigger than screen size.

Loot at this page: http://go-mstudio.com/ in iphone or ipad and open link "ajax". The overlay will be only screen size and then goes white.

How van I fix it?

Comment: do you mean, the content inside fancybox is visible partially (screen size) and then when you scroll down is just white?

Comment: Yes, I do!

Overlay is white bottomer to the screen height.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/8912218/1055987 if that helps